# Tool to generate DTO mapping based on entity model, configurable from UI

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, entity-framework, jakarta-ee, mapstruct

I'm looking for a framework that takes an existing entity model and derives a hibernate query based on a configurable mapping to a DTO model, from a UI.

So, basically I have an entity model in my Java2EE / SpringBoot application. Of course I don't want to push an entity to the UI all the time.

Instead it would be great to have a tool that not only does a simple DTO mapping. I know there are tools like MapStruct that does that for me. Instead of that simple DTO mapping the tool should analyse the entity model based on a convention class or annotation (or configuration file) and spit out a generated DTO and the hibernate query.

Additionally I'd like to manipulate those configuration files from the UI during runtime.

In other words: I want to generate a query based on the entity model, but configurable during runtime and map the result into (generated) DTOs and present them in the UI.

Any further questions?

Any suggestions?